# extra tooltip for displaying yAxis values on right side

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want an extra tooltip in my highchart which will display `yAxis` value. These tooltips which I am talking about you have seen in many ohlc charts. For demonstration purpose, I've made it using paint tool.

[image: Tooltip on right side 1]

[image: Tooltip on right side 2]

If you see on the right side, along with the main tooltip, there's another tooltip which is showing the `yAxis` value. How can we make the same in highcharts. I am having following code.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Non-snapped crosshair'
    },
    xAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            snap: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            snap: false
        },
        opposite: true
    },
    tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        shape: 'rect',
        positioner: function () {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 };
        },
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

**Note:** For having crosshair which follows mouse pointer, I am setting `snap` property of `crosshair` in both the axis to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `highstock` source code and the `label` property for crosshair:

```
yAxis: {
    crosshair: {
        snap: false,
        label: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{value:.2f}'
        }
    },
    ...
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yz4b6cus/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.crosshair.label